# Different iOS and Android version numbers reported by react-native-device-info

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am attempting to display my app's version number with `react-native-device-info` however I am finding that it is different between the Android and iOS apps, with Android reporting the correct version but iOS is showing `1.0`...

How would I sync these up?

Comment: You can change the version for ios from `info.plist` file with the corresponding version on  Android version.

Comment: In case you submit App to Store/TestFlight. Apple Version convention must be enforced.

Comment: @FistonEmmanuel is there a way to keep these the same as we push updates in future?

Comment: No.for existing users to upgrade to the new version release, Google Play or App Store depends on previous version.

Comment: There are some situations where you need to fix a bug or issue related to a specific platform (iOS or Android) and you are forced to release on that platform only and increase the version number. Synchronizing version for all platforms is not always an option.